# puxar registro e filtrar do mysql pro php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando puxar as informações no MySql e mostrar no php, com um filtro no nome da sala

```
$reserva = mysqli_query($connect, 'select * from reserva join curso on reserva.idCurso = curso.idCurso join professor on reserva.idProfessor = professor.idProfessor join sala on reserva.idSala = sala.idSala;');
$reservaArray = mysqli_fetch_array($reserva);
$selectSala = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM sala') or die('Deu erro');
    while($teste = mysqli_fetch_array($selectSala)){
        $arraySala[] = $teste['nomeSala'];
    }

for ($sala=9; $sala<=20; $sala++){
          echo   '<tr>
                 <th scope="row">'.$arraySala[$sala].'</th>
                 <td colspan="3" class="text-center">';
                       if($arraySala[$sala] == $reservaArray['nomeSala']){
                             echo $reservaArray['idCurso'].' - '.$reservaArray['nomeCurso'].' - '.$reservaArray['nomeProfessor']; 
                        }

                  echo'</td>
          </tr>';
      }
```

existem 3 registro, mas apenas o primeiro é mostrado. Já tentei usar o `while` mas não consegui executar

Comment: essa é a segunda parte da tabela, então comecei 1 a mais da anterior

Comment: Olá @jhonata bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor adicione o código que faz a consulta ao banco de dados para complementar a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oque pude notar é que está passando no for o index da array, e está começar com 9, a array se inicia com o index 0, e nesse caso seria também mais simples utilizar um foreach.

```
for ($sala=0; $sala<=20; $sala++){
          echo   '<tr>
                 <th scope="row">'.$arraySala[$sala].'</th>';
}

foreach (arraySala $value){
//conteúdo do loop
}
```

você pode obter mais detalhes no uso do foreach em:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php